# Changing colors of drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, drawrect

I drew a line using `drawRect`. Now I want to change the color of it.

Example Code: `self.pattern.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

I need to be able to change the color of the `drawRect` like that code. I get stuck on the second part of the code.

`self. ? . backgroundColor`:   The questions marks is where i get stuck. What should I put there for a `drawRect`?

Here is some code from my `drawRect` too:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Setup background
    //CGFloat components1[] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
    //CGColorSpaceRef colorspace1 = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    ////CGColorRef black = CGColorCreate(colorspace1, components1);
    //CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,black);
    //CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    //  1 pixel: iphone 6 the point = 0.5 and 6 plus = 0.333333;
    //CGFloat point =1.f/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGFloat point =width/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context,point);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat red []   = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}; // green
    CGFloat green [] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0}; // green
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, green);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    if(bFirstLine && bAlter)
    {
        CGColorRef colorR = CGColorCreate(colorspace, red);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, colorR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIColor redColor] setFill]; // to set the color for fillings
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke]; // to set the color for strokes
```

and in your case (if i got you right):

```
[self.backgroundColor setFill];
[self.backgroundColor setStroke];
```

Comment: I want to change the color of the drawRect like 'self. ? . backgroundColor'.  How can i change the color of the draw rect like that with this? I implemented it, but it doesn't work, unless it put it in the draw rect code.